# Elastic Beanstalk pause time not honored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a time-based rolling update configured on one of our Elastic Beanstalk services. I have set the 'pause time' to be 5 minutes. This should mean that the next batch will only be updated after 5 minutes. But what I observe is that the next batch is started directly when the health checks pass. This is unexpected and unwanted in my case because a restart of multiple batches gives a high load on some of our API's. I want the rollout to be slow (where everyone wants it to be fast :-) ). What am I missing here?